# wait for process in pipeline returns wrong exit code

Tags: bash

I must be missing something here:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 5 sleep 10 &
parent_pid=$( ps --pid $! -o ppid --no-headers )
timeout_pid=$( pgrep --parent $parent_pid timeout )
wait $timeout_pid
echo "exit code: $?"
```

Call the script `wait-pid` and run:

```
$ ./wait-pid 
exit code: 124
```

which is what I expect, `timeout` kills the `sleep` process and exits with 124, which `wait` dutifully returns.

But if I add a pipeline to the initial command:

```
timeout 5 sleep 10 | cat &
parent_pid=$( ps --pid $! -o ppid --no-headers )
timeout_pid=$( pgrep --parent $parent_pid timeout )
wait $timeout_pid
echo "exit code: $?"
```

now I get:

```
$ ./wait-pid 
exit code: 0
```

Shouldn't `wait` still return the exit code of the process that it's waiting on: `timeout`. So shouldn't the exit code still be 124.

This is with bash 4.4.20(1)-release.

Comment: Note: replace `cat` with `sh -c 'cat; exit 17'` and see what happens.

Comment: Nice idea. As you might have guessed I get `exit code: 17`. So `wait` is returning the exit code of the whole pipeline. Why isn't it returning the exit code of the process that it's waiting on?

Comment: If I knew, I would have already written a good answer. :)

Comment: and just for clarity, in the version of this that I actually run I verify that the pid I wait for really does belong to `timeout` (by echoing the pid and verifying against `watch pstree <bash-pid> -p -a`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received an answer from the super-knowledgeable Greg Wooledge on the bash mailing list. The key element is:

> The wait command only works on direct child processes of the shell, a.k.a.
> "asynchronous commands".  In the case where your asynchronous command is
> a pipeline, we fall back to the original sh feature set.  The exit status
> of your asynchronous command is that of the last command in the pipeline,
> and the other commands' exit statuses are simply discarded.

So that's why I don't get the exit code of `timeout` when it's in a pipeline.

The way to get the behaviour I want is to use a temporary file to capture exit codes from within the asynchronous code. Something like:

```
{
  timeout 5 sleep 10 | cat
  echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" > "$tempfile"
} &
wait
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems in case of a pipeline, `wait` waits for the entire pipeline to exit, even if you give it PID(s) of specific process(es) and they exit early; and even if the exit status is known early because the last command in the pipeline also exits early. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653472/108618).