# bash wait on process is halting even after process termination

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to script this to determine the start of the mariadb test container. `port: 3306` is the last line in `podman logs -f` and there isn't much expected after this (hence the attempt kill the `podman logs` process rather relying on SIGPIPE).

```bsh
  set -x -v; \
  podman run -d --name mdb_test -P -e MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1  mariadb:10.6 ; \
  podman logs -f mdb_test 2>&1 | grep -m1 'port: 3306' & \
  pid_grep=$! ; \
  pid_podman_logs=$(jobs -p); \
  jobs; \
  wait $pid_grep; \
  kill $pid_podman_logs; \
  port=$(podman port mdb_test 3306); \
  mysql -u root --protocol tcp --port ${port#*:}  -e 'select version()';
```

Output:

```bsh
+ set -x -v
+ podman run -d --name mdb_test -P -e MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 mariadb:10.6
299b645a84b278d2ffcfb776bf12cf282a0695131bf77a02f0c7701a9ea1868b
[1]+  Done                    podman logs -f mdb_test 2>&1 | grep -m1 'port: 3306'
[1] 2414801
+ pid_grep=2414801
+ podman logs -f mdb_test
+ grep -m1 'port: 3306'
++ jobs -p
+ pid_podman_logs=2414800
+ jobs
[1]+  Running                 podman logs -f mdb_test 2>&1 | grep -m1 'port: 3306' &
+ wait 2414801
Version: '10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

I'd like to know why the shell has stopped at `wait` and not progressing even though the `grep` has terminated (and `podman logs` is still running).

Any other scripting improvements welcome.

Edit simpler version:

```bsh
set -x -v ; (echo "bob"; sleep 100000) | grep -m1 bob & pid_grep=$!; pid_echo=$(jobs -p); jobs ; wait $pid_grep; kill $pid_echo; echo ready
+ set -x -v
[1] 2417616
+ pid_grep=2417616
+ grep -m1 bob
+ echo bob
+ sleep 100000
++ jobs -p
+ pid_echo=2417615
+ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ( echo "bob"; sleep 100000 ) | grep -m1 bob &
+ wait 2417616
bob
```

Looking at ps in another shell the grep is finished.

Comment: What is the output of plain old `jobs`? Because you can kill each job with things like `kill %1`.

Comment: I wanted to wait for the `grep` to terminate after its first match. Replacing `wait` with `while kill -0 $pid_grep; do : ; done`  actually exhibited the behavior wanted (but ugly). Could it be `wait` is implicitly waiting on the process group leader `podman logs`?

Comment: You could replace `kill -0` with `wait`.

Comment: `wait` in a `while` loop?  The `wait` doesn't complete on its own so adding it in a loop won't help. I did try, same behaviour as original question.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/356154/9782169.

Comment: Why do you have all those unnecessary semi-colons and backslashes at the ends of your script lines?  If that's a one-liner that you're trying to make more readable for this site then....don't. Put it in a script and use your favourite editor to edit it. You'll find that much less hassle than trying to edit something like that on the command line.

Comment: apologizes @cas. I will next time.

Comment: Reformatting for the site is fine, I meant that editing ridiculously long command lines in the shell is a PITA (even with ^X^E or similar to edit the current line in $EDITOR), hard to read and understand, and extremely prone to human error.   i.e. it's just making your job harder, making problems for yourself.

Comment: It *seems* when a job is a pipeline so there are many simultaneous processes in it that are children of the shell, `wait`ing for any of them actually waits for all of them. I haven't found documentation that states this clearly, so it's something I can only confirm by testing (and that's why this comment is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: Another unexpected behavior of `wait` and a pipeline here: [*`wait` for process in pipeline returns wrong exit code*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653369/108618). It may be somewhat related to your case. Not only `wait` returns the exit code of the entire pipeline, it also waits for the entire pipeline, even if the exit code can be determined earlier.

Comment: See also [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/416162) (and other Q&As linked from there) for a simpler approach.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for sharing.  @StéphaneChazelas the difficulty was I was looking for what's likely to be the last line in`podman logs` for a potentially very long time so there's no more stdout to trigger the SIGPIPE. I need to learn more shells I guess, or just stick to polling or coproc.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you're going about this the entirely wrong way.

The correct way to see if a process is listening on a port and responding correctly is to connect to it and query it.   The best that grepping the log will do is tell you that was listening at some time in the past, not that it is actually listening now - it may have died sometime between the log entry and now.

So, start mysql and use a while loop to see if mysql is responding correctly.  Sleep for a few seconds in each iteration of the loop.

Your entire script can be replaced with something like the following - no need for background jobs, waiting, killing pids, etc:

```bsh
podman run -d --name mdb_test -P -e MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1  mariadb:10.6

# I'm not sure why you need to do this rather than just 'port=3306', but I don't
# know podman. Maybe it's necessary for some kind of namespace port mapping.
port=$(podman port mdb_test 3306)
port=${port#*:}

MYSQL_VERSION=""
while [[ ! "$MYSQL_VERSION" =~ ^Version ]] ; do
   sleep 2
   MYSQL_VERSION=$(mysql -u root --protocol tcp --port "$port"  -e 'select version()')
done
echo "$MYSQL_VERSION"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cas. I was doing something [similar already](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/710e0cd/.test/run.sh#L42) (which is probably uglier), and I was seeing if there was a non-polling way and assumed bash was good at job management. The server code does have ports listening by the time `port: 3306` was printed but good point about "may have dies" (though there's very little code between the two). FYI the port hackery is that the exposed port isn't the same as the internal port (though there are ways to anchor the numbering). Thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

coproc is one way:

```bsh
set -x -v; \
podman run -d --name mdb_test -P -e MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1  mariadb:10.6 ; \
coproc podman logs -f mdb_test 2>&1; \
pid_podman_logs=${COPROC_PID}; \
grep -m1 'port: 3306' <&"${COPROC[0]}"; \
kill $pid_podman_logs; \
port=$(podman port mdb_test 3306); \
mysql -u root --protocol tcp --port ${port#*:}  -e 'select version()';
```

Output:

```bsh
+ set -x -v
+ podman run -d --name mdb_test -P -e MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 mariadb:10.6
c8bc23b8b7b0c34e1037f28797f34184e768f7def9ee220f2b8760484a2d798e
[1] 2420140
+ pid_podman_logs=2420140
+ grep -m1 'port: 3306'
+ podman logs -f mdb_test
Version: '10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
+ kill 2420140
++ podman port mdb_test 3306
+ port=0.0.0.0:34497
+ mysql -u root --protocol tcp --port 34497 -e 'select version()'
+-------------------------------------+
| version()                           |
+-------------------------------------+
| 10.6.1-MariaDB-1:10.6.1+maria~focal |
+-------------------------------------+
[1]+  Exit 1                  coproc COPROC podman logs -f mdb_test 2>&1
```

So for the simpler version:

```bsh
set -x -v ; coproc (echo "bob"; sleep 100000) ; pid_echo=${COPROC_PID};  grep -m1 bob  <&"${COPROC[0]}" <&"${COPROC[0]}" ; kill $pid_echo; echo ready
+ set -x -v
[1] 2418707
+ pid_echo=2418707
+ grep -m1 bob
+ echo bob
+ sleep 100000
bob
+ kill 2418707
+ echo ready
ready
```